# How to reverse a NonEmpty in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, reverse

This time, I am faced with the task of reversing a `NonEmpty`.

I am trying this (I know that it does not do what we require it to, yet assume this is a MWE):

```
reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
reverseNonEmpty (x :| []) = x :| []
reverseNonEmpty (x :| xs) = (x :| tail xs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (reverseNonEmpty (1 :| [2, 3, 4])) -- Prints "1 :| [3,4]"
```

The above snippet is the first version that compiles. However, I am puzzled with Haskell syntax for `NonEmpty`'s (I am a beginner here).

Q: How do I make it reverse input `NonEmpty`s?

Comment: There's not really "Haskell syntax for `NonEmpty`s". [`NonEmpty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) is just a data type like any other, and `:|` its constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it in terms of the `reverse` function for lists like this:

```
reverseNonEmpty :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
reverseNonEmpty (x :| xs) = case Prelude.reverse xs of
                            []     -> x :| []
                            (y:ys) -> y :| (ys ++ [x])
```

This approach however is not optimal because it traverses the list twice, `reverse` and `++`.

Another possibility is with an accumulator helper function for example:

```
reverseNonEmpty (x :| xs) = reverseAcc xs (x :| [])

reverseAcc :: [a] -> NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
reverseAcc []     acc = acc
reverseAcc (x:xs) acc = reverseAcc xs (x :| toList acc)
```

This solution repeatedly constructs and destructs the nonempty constructor `:|`.

In `Data.List.NonEmpty` the reverse function is defined as a lifting of the list reverse function:

```
reverse = lift List.reverse
```

This approach is the most efficient, because it does some constant time conversion, a linear pass and a final constant time conversion.

Comment: Note that the first option is not optimal because it traverses the list twice (reverse & ++). And the second repeatedly constructs and destructs the nonempty constructor `:|`. The last approach is the most efficient, because it just does some constant time conversion then a linear pass and then a final constant time conversion.

Comment: @Noughtmare You might like my answer, which discusses an implementation that could plausibly be viewed as what a sufficiently smart compiler would produce given `lift List.reverse`.

Answer (score 3):

The other extant answer does a good job of describing various alternatives for implementations, but those alternatives seem to appear out of whole cloth. In this answer, I will attempt to show how you could go about inventing the answer yourself. I will start by assuming you have already grokked the standard tricks for implementing `reverse` on plain lists, and show how with simple, local transformations you can turn that implementation into one that works on non-empty lists.

Here's the standard implementation of `reverse` for plain lists:

```
reverse xs = go [] xs where
    go as [] = as
    go as (b:bs) = go (b:as) bs
```

We'd like to modify this so that our recursive function is only called on non-empty lists (i.e. plain old lists that we know are not empty, not `NonEmpty`s). So everywhere we call `go`, just before we do the call, we'll do a pattern match. If we *would* have called `go` on an empty list, we'll just inline what `go` would have done so that we don't have to call it. For example, instead of `go [] xs`, we'll do a case on `xs` to check whether it's empty and only call `go` when it isn't, like this:

```
reverse [] = [] -- inline the call go [] []
reverse (x:xs) = go [] (x:xs) {- no inlining, do the same call we would usually do -} where
    go as [] = as -- no change at all from before, since there's no recursive call
    go as (b:[]) = b:as -- inline the call go (b:as) []
    go as (b:b':bs) = go (b:as) (b':bs) -- no inlining, do the same call we would usually do
```

Now that we know `go`'s argument is always non-empty, we can remove that case from the definition of `go`. All other cases remain exactly the same.

```
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = go [] (x:xs) where
    go as (b:[]) = b:as
    go as (b:b':bs) = go (b:as) (b':bs)
```

Now it's a bit odd that we're pattern-matching on the second argument to `go` to extract the first element of the list given that we know all callers have just done the same pattern match already. So let's just change the calling convention a little: callers will pass the already-matched first list element separately. Like this:

```
reverse [] = []
reverse (x:xs) = go [] x xs where
    go as b [] = b:as
    go as b (b':bs) = go (b:as) b' bs
```

Given this definition, it is now extremely easy to implement `weirdReverse :: NonEmpty a -> [a]`: simply ignore the first defining clause for empty inputs, since we know they don't exist! Of course we also have to change the `:` to a `:|` in the outer pattern match.

```
weirdReverse :: NonEmpty a -> [a]
weirdReverse (x:|xs) {- swap out constructors -} = go [] x xs where
    go as b [] = b:as
    go as b (b':bs) = go (b:as) b' bs
```

Finally, since `go` now clearly syntactically always returns a list with at least one element, it's easy to swap out the `:` in its return value for a `:|` to return a `NonEmpty` instead of a `[]`.

```
neReverse :: NonEmpty a -> NonEmpty a
neReverse (x:|xs) = go [] x xs where
    go as b [] = b:|as -- swap out constructors
    go as b (b':bs) = go (b:as) b' bs
```

This pattern -- of implementing `NonEmpty` functions in essentially the same way as their `[]` counterparts, but "unrolling" each definition one layer and adding an argument for the known head -- is quite general; it should work well for things like `map`, `foldr`, `zip`, `last`, `init`, and so forth. I encourage you to give it a shot, as it's excellent exercise! If you want to start with a particularly similar one, try `last`.